# How to do server side validation in spring mvc for dynamically added fields using jquery

Tags: spring-mvc

i am looking forward to do server side validation in spring mvc for dynamically added fields using jquery.
let's say there is a page where i have to add Child and parent details, i have add more option to add multiple Child. How do i validate child dynamic fields from server side using spring mvc.